# Syntax Error When Installing Package

Tags: python, pip, package

When using pip to install SpeechRecognition on a virtual environment (Python 2.6), I keep getting the following error:

> File "speech_recognition/__ init __.py", line 1046 if system ==
>   "Windows" and machine in {"i686", "i786", "x86", "x86_64", "AMD64"}:
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Installing other packages on this environment works just fine. Any way to fix this?

Comment: That collection is a *set literal* which doesn't exist in python2.6. I don't have much advice as to why pip is grabbing a non-2.6-compatible package, but just pointing out the source of the syntax error.

Comment: maybe do `pip --version` to make sure the `pip` you're using is the one you think you're using